# Post to XML API via email?

Tags: xml, api, email

I am being forced to use a dashboard for a product that has a form, this form can ONLY send to  an email address that I can designate. My problem: I need this form to get into an API... Is there a way to send an email that somehow posts to an API? The API accepts an XML body.

Comment: You have asked 4 questions eligible to be accepted, but have accepted none.  Suggest you have a look and see if any of the answers you received were good and worthy of being accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the external API is going to an email address, your only available starting point is to read email designated for that address and reformat the data for your XML API.

Depending on the exact platform, generally I would consider a service / demon process that periodically checks for new email at the given address, parses the body of each email, and sends the resulting request to your API.

Robustness is challenging in this type of situation.

I suggest at a minimum that you log all email received to a file, and log the success / failure of submitting each message to your API to facilitate trouble shooting and correcting problems in production.